# Finitely generated abelian groups: If $G \times K$ is isomorphic to $H \times K$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G,H,K$ be finitely generated abelian groups.  If $G \times  K$ is isomorphic to $H \times K$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $H$.

What I have thought is that fundamental theorem of abelian groups can be used, but I don't know how to do next.  Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What does the Fundamental Theorem of finitely generated groups have to say about groups $G, H, K$? And $\;G\times K\;$ and $\;H \times K\;?\;$

- $G,\;H,\;K.\; G\times K,\;\text{and}\;\;H\times K\;$ are each isomorphic to, and can be expressed ***uniquely*** (up to the order of the factors) as, the direct product, whose factors all are cyclic groups of order the power of a prime and/or $\mathbb Z$.

What does this imply if $G\times K \cong H\times K$, each of which is the direct product of abelian groups which are themselves the direct product of cyclic groups?

Then $K$ be *uniquely* decomposed into the direct product of cyclic groups. The same for $G\times K$ and $H \times K$, each of which must include all the factors in the in the decomposition of $K$. Then  after taking into account there common factors, since  $G\times K \cong H \times K$, what must be true about $G$ and $H$?

Comment: (This doesn't really affect your answer too much, the claim is not that $G$, $H$, and $K$ are finite groups, but rather that they are finitely generated.)

Comment: I can understand that G$\times$K and H$\times$K include the factors of the decomposition of K. But, I don't know how to show G is isomorphic to K by this fact.

Comment: What is left of $G\times K$ and $H\times K$, after accounting for their shared factors of the decomposition of $K$? After all, we are given $G\times K \cong H \times K$. I.e., the only way $G\times K \cong H\times K$ is if the decomposition in factors is identical, up to the order of the factors. Taking into account that each decomposition included common factors of $K$, the factors of $G$ must be the factors of $H$: i.e., $G\cong H$

Comment: Now, I understand. Thx alot

Comment: Am I right that in your solution you are using the fact that $G\times K$ and $H\times K$ is finitely generated?

Answer (score 3):

Or if you access to *A Course on Group Theory by J.J.Rose* see this:

> Corollary 8.42: Let $G$ be a non-trivial finitely generated abelian group and let $$G=H_1\times...\times H_m=K_1\times ....\times K_n$$ where $m,n$ are positive integers and $H_i,K_j$ are non-trivial indecomposable subgroups of $G$ Then $m=n$ and, by relabeling the suffices if necessary, $$H_i=K_j$$ for each $i=1,...n$

Comment: $+1 \quad \ddot\smile\;$

Comment: $-1$ (I don't know if the OP will find this answer useful or not, but for me is not!)

Comment: @user: `...If someone hits you on the cheek, offer them the other cheek...` Jesus Christ. So thank you. :-)

Comment: Actually I'd deduce other things from the downvote: for example to not give a reference instead of an elaborate answer, especially to simple questions as the present one.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Thanks! And a positive one for your recent post in return. :+)